# When I use SVN to import a project in Myeclipse or STS, will the project's directory structure be different?

Tags: svn, spring-tool-suite, myeclipse

When I use SVN to import a project in Myeclipse or STS, will the project's directory structure be different?
I think it is the same, but it has not been verified.
Someone told me that MyEclipse uses 'Webroot' and STS uses 'webcontent', but I think it only appears in the new project. If I use the SVN import project, it won't be different.

Comment: as far as I know the IDE doesn't magically change the folder names or structures of your project if you import them (either via SVN or from the file system).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Martin Lippert mentioned, the SVN plugin won't change any folder names in your project; it will be the way it was saved in SVN. If it's a maven project and you're using Maven4MyEclipse or m2e to import it as a maven project, the same applies, though other files and folders may be created to turn it into an eclipse project.